# Faulty audits in Review queue

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-audits, triage, english

I've come across a couple of bad audits in the Review queue. Both resulted in fails as the post was alleged to be spam or nonsense. In neither case was this true. Lost the first one last week but today's one is here:  https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7315977.

The post is written in Russian and when translated is neither spam nor nonsense. It should certainly be translated, closed, or deleted, as this site is conducted in English, but I was unable to find a valid reason when I tried that, so I went for 'should be improved' and got the fail.

I suggest there's enough fuzziness about all this that it shouldn't be used as an audit.

Comment: The post was not deleted as spam. It was just deleted, without a specific reason given.

Comment: @RetoKoradi I didn't say it was 'deleted as spam'. It was shown to me when I failed the audit as 'spam or nonsense'.

Comment: You say "it should certainly be closed or deleted" yet you chose "should be improved" instead of "unsalvageable". Why would you do that?

Comment: @l4mpi Because I left out 'translated'.

Comment: @EJP so you think sending a non-english question to the help and improvement queue is a good idea? You also seem to think it would be a good idea for somebody else than OP to translate it, which I don't think is reasonable at all as there are so many problems with that - there's a strong indication OP is unable to communicate in english, the translation accurracy can only be checked by people speaking both languages (think suggested edits; or accountability - did OP actually say this or was it snuck in during translation), potential rollback wars, etc, etc.

Comment: You say "I suggest there's enough fuzziness about all this that it shouldn't be used as an audit" - I don't get this at all. If you arrive at a post that is simply gibberish (which it is, given you don't understand the language - and the language of SO is english), then _it should be closed with extreme prejudice_. You have to consult google translate just to find out if there is even a potentially valid question in there. That's an extreme indication that a question is not fit for this site and should be closed as  "unclear" or with a custom reason ("not in english").

Answer (score 12):

I don't read Russian. Neither do most readers - that's *why* we have that English-only rule here. Nothing against Russians, but... To most readers here, that *is* nonsense.

For future reference, "Should be closed -> Off topic -> Other" is the correct option upon encountering such questions. If you do happen to possess the ability to communicate in Russian, pointing the author to [this proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41168/stack-overflow-in-russian) would probably be a helpful thing to do.

Comment: I agree that it doesn't belong here, and I've already said so myself, but not providing me with a plausible close reason and then telling me it was 'spam or nonsense' when it wasn't isn't correct. I don't speak Russian but I was interested enough to paste it into Google Translate. 'Needs improvement', i.e. translation into English, is a perfectly valid response.

Comment: @EJP: Actually, it isn't. It presupposes that the asker is perfectly all right with commenting and getting answers in english, when evidence to the contrary is quite strong.

Comment: @EJP - The "spam or nonsense" bit comes from the fact that someone did flag that as spam, and the spam flag was accepted when the post was deleted. I cleared that flag so that label shouldn't appear again, but that post still should have been closed, spam label or no.

Comment: @Deduplicator At the time I did the review the evidence available to me about that was zero. The question itself was perfectly valid as an SO question. Whether an answer in English would have actually helped the OP is another question, and not our problem.

Comment: option "Should be closed -> Off topic -> Other" is only available for users with 3K+ rep - what would you recommend to those who can't pick it?

Comment: ->EJP: Ehm, you are saying you didn't see it was non-english, but you pasted it into an online translator to get a bad english translation anyway? @gnat Those who cannot pick off-topic -> other -> "non-english", can just use "unclear" for wrong language.

Comment: The "other" option is replaced with "blatantly off-topic" for flaggers, @gnat - that works too.

Comment: thanks Shog, that makes sense. I looks like "unclear" (suggested in [prior comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287907/faulty-audits-in-review-queue/287908#comment169006_287908) by @Deduplicator) makes a reasonable option for flaggers, too (CCCP - /\EH\/\H)

Comment: @Deduplicator I didn't say anything about not seeing that it wasn't English. Don't put words into my mouth.